# How to create temporary URL in OpenStack using python-swiftclient?

Tags: python, openstack, object-storage

I'm using the [python-swiftclient](https://pypi.org/project/python-swiftclient/) to connect to an OpenStack Object Store. Following [some examples from the documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/python-swiftclient/latest/client-api.html) I can now upload a file:

```
container = 'new-container'
local_file_path = 'file.txt'

conn = Connection(**OBJECT_STORE_INFO)
with open(local_file_path, 'r') as local:
    r = conn.put_object(
        container,
        local_file_path,
        contents=local.read(),
        content_type='application/zip'
    )
    print("File created")
```

This works great and I now want to create a temporary URL for that file. In the sources I found [the function generate_temp_url()](https://github.com/openstack/python-swiftclient/blob/master/swiftclient/utils.py#L74-L200), which needs at least four arguments: path, seconds, key, method

For the path, [the documentation says](https://github.com/openstack/python-swiftclient/blob/master/swiftclient/utils.py#L79-L81):

```
:param path: The full path to the Swift object or prefix if
    a prefix-based temporary URL should be generated. Example:
    /v1/AUTH_account/c/o or /v1/AUTH_account/c/prefix.
```

and I'm having trouble finding this path. I tried a couple variations (my local path, the URL of the file I get from the web interface) but nothing works. I can get the headers about the file

```
resp_headers = conn.head_object(container, local_file_path)
```

which returns this:

```
{'content-length': '12', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'last-modified': 'Wed, 10 Feb 2021 16:10:19 GMT', 
'etag': '4d79d5df13513c295916112b9b3e25e0', 'x-timestamp': '1612973418.28837', 
'content-type': 'text/plain', 'x-trans-id': 'tx045dc3b415374a81a9a80-00602407c4', 
'date': 'Wed, 10 Feb 2021 16:20:20 GMT', 'age': '0', 'via': 'our.objectstore.com'}
```

But that doesn't show any helpful information.

In [this documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/python-swiftclient/latest/cli/index.html#swift-tempurl) it gives the following example:

> Example: /v1/AUTH_account/c/o or: http://saio:8080/v1/AUTH_account/c/o

The direct url to my file is: https://8d078638c1a547c09e0b5f34834554f1.ourobjectstore.com/new-container/file.txt

So that doesn't resemble the URLs in the example at all.

What is happening here? Where can I find this so called "path" so that I can create the temp URL?

Comment: Please check the Official Guide link [here](https://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/config-reference/content/object-storage-tempurl.html) regarding create temp url in open stack. May be you are missing some important point.

Comment: without having looked too much into the issue, the docs linked in the comment above are a bit dated - the icehouse release was 6 years ago. The current release is victoria, with the temp-url docs being [here](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/victoria/api/temporary_url_middleware.html)

Comment: I'm hesitant to post this as an answer, because I can't test it, but as far as I can tell, the path should be interpreted like / v1 / AUTH_[auth_user_account] / [container_name] / [file name maybe?] .  TempURL is a middleware and needs to be installed/supported by the server.  https://docs.openstack.org/swift/victoria/middleware.html#tempurl and https://docs.openstack.org/swift/victoria/api/temporary_url_middleware.html . It will then be a part of "The Auth System" https://docs.openstack.org/swift/victoria/overview_auth.html More: https://www.swiftstack.com/docs/admin/middleware/tempurl.html

Comment: Another good link:  https://www.swiftstack.com/docs/cookbooks/swift_usage/auth.html

Comment: @RakshaSaini - Your pointer to the official documentation helped me get on the right path. It was a link to a very old version. So after some searching around I found a similar page in the current documentation here: https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/api/temporary_url_middleware.html
From there I adjusted the example code and added it here as an answer.

Comment: @RakshaSaini - My own answer is the right answer, but I'd be happy to award you the 500 bounty. If you add your suggestion as an answer I'll accept my own answer as the correct answer and I'll award you the 500 points.

Comment: @kramer65 Thanks for the appreciation. I try to give the approxmatly solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66252778/3607051).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end @RakshaSaini wrote the first comment pointing me to [the official documentation here](https://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/config-reference/content/object-storage-tempurl.html). It contained an example which didn't work, but was close enough. I adjusted it as follows and now it works for us:

```
import hmac
from hashlib import sha1
from time import time
method = 'GET'
duration_in_seconds = 60 * 60 * 24  # 24 hours
expires = int(time() + duration_in_seconds)
path = '/new-container/file.txt'
key = b'the-temp-url-key'
hmac_body = f'{method}\n{expires}\n{path}'.encode('utf-8')
sig = hmac.new(key, hmac_body, sha1).hexdigest()
url = f'https://tenantid.ourobjectstore.com{path}?temp_url_sig={sig}&temp_url_expires={expires}'
print("URL", url)
```